# Extremepoints of function with two variables

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

$f(x,y)=x\cdot y(ax+by+c)\quad x,y>0\quad abc\neq 0\\ $

Partial Derivatives:

${ f }_{ x }=y(ax+by+c)+axy\\ { f }_{ y }=x(ax+by+c)+byx$

How do I find the critical Points out of The system of equations beneath, aren't they depended on the behaviour of a,b,c

$y(ax+by+c)+axy=0$

$x(ax+by+c)+byx=0$

Comment: Your partial derivatives are not correct.

Comment: thanks for pointing it out i edited it, and thanks for the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The partial derivatives are
$$f_x = y(2ax + by + c),$$
$$f_y = x(ax + 2by +c).$$

Since $x,y >0$, we just need to solve the system
$$\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
2ax + by + c = 0\\
ax + 2by +c = 0\\
\end{array}\right.$$

to find the critical points. It should be easy from there.

Answer (score 3):

As $\textit{Integral}$ pointed out, your partial derivatives are not correct:

Note that

$$f(x,y)=yax^2+bxy^2+xyc$$

Then
$${ f }_{ x }=2yax+by^2+yc$$ 
and 
$${ f }_{ y }=ax^2+2bxy+xc$$

So you only need to equate this two expressions with $0$ to find the extreme points:
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
2yax+by^2+yc = y\cdot(2ax+by+c) = 2ax+by+c = 0\\
ax^2+2bxy+xc = x\cdot(ax+2by+c) = ax+2by+c = 0\\
\end{array}\right.$$

So you find 3 solutions:

$y = 0\ $ if $\ c = 0$, $a = 0$ and $b\neq0 \to$ not possible (because $abc\neq0$!)

$x = 0\ $ if $\ c = 0$, $b = 0$ and $a\neq0 \to$ not possible (because $abc\neq0$!)

Can you find the third (and the only one possible) solution?

Comment: if i take c=-3by than i get ax-by=0 and that happens only if x,y=0 or a,b=0? but that would contradict to waht we supposed

Comment: sorry i miss concluded, i need to take y=c/(-3b) and x =c/(-3a) and thats my only possible point for a Min or Max

Comment: Exactly! Well done.